# Are my coins lost?

Tags: e-wallet

I think that the answer to this question is yes, unfortunately.

I had an online bitcoin wallet and I still know my bitcoin address, but I can't remember where it was hosted. Or perhaps it is shut down.

Is there any way to recover this, or to at least work out the site where the address was registered?

Comment: huh?  What do you mean you "know the address but can't remember where it was hosted?" EDIT: I think you mean you have the bitcoin address but can't remember the URL for what site it was on.?

Answer (score 2):

Well there's only a finite number, unless you were using some crazy hidden tor service...  Do you know if this is a proper wallet or actually a store account?

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:EWallets
http://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:HybridEWallets

Check browser history, google search history if it's enabled, check for backup files in dropbox or google drive.  Look in your saved password list in your browser.  Try some undelete tools to look through already-deleted browser history.  Just think like what the FBI would do if they needed to find something!

Answer (score 1):

Look for your address on blockchain.info. There is a list of outgoing transactions from this address. Sometimes you can find the IP address, or even the name of the sender, e.g. SatoshiDice, Slush.

Here is an example link: http://blockchain.info/pl/address/1CRACKafkXsQzUYmu2fUM3j9c2y4yDhvfh